# Command called too late

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, command, eventtrigger

I have a `ComboBox` that looks like this:

```
 <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Mode}" SelectedValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding MyModes}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SetModeCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl,Mode=FindAncestor}}"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsForSet}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" ></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </ComboBox>
```

SelectedValue and ItemsSource are bind to variables in the model.

And the command: `SetModeCommand` sitting in ViewModel.

I want that command will not work when changing the variable in the model, but will only work when changing it through the UI.

So I created a variable called `IsForSet` (bool) and when I change the variable `Mode` through the model I put it false :

```
IsForSetUM = false;
Mode = 202;
IsForSetUM = true;
```

My problem is that the command is not called as soon as I change the `Mode`. But only after I change the `IsForSetUM` to true.

**I have a solution to this!!**

**My question** is why the command is not called immediately when I change the `Mode`?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but if you set the ComboBox SelectedValue Binding Mode to Mode=TwoWay then changes to your Model / ViewModel should be reflected immediately in the UI (providing that your Model/ViewModel property implements INotifyPropertyChanged).

Comment: @RichardE based on the OP's description you'd actually need `Mode=OneWayToSource` to ensure changes are only from View -> VM /Model

Comment: @Viv I do not want changes to be only from View ... I want that the command will work only when changing from View.

Comment: @RichardE It works with TwoWay mode, otherwise it would not change the value in the ComboBox.

Comment: Could you change your event trigger to listen for the DopDownClosed event rather than the SelectionChanged event?

Comment: @RichardE... It can be a good idea! But I'm wondering why the command does not start immediately when the mode changes

Comment: @RichardE if I pass mode with the keys of the keyboard is not running the event .. So it's problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set NotifyOnSourceUpdated on your Binding to true and use the SourceUpdated event in your EventTrigger like so:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Mode, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" SelectedValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding MyModes}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SourceUpdated">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SetModeCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl,Mode=FindAncestor}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" ></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ComboBox>
```